# SQL Server query is very slow when number of items inside IN clause more than 4

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance, in-clause

I have some complicated query with joins of many tables. It is difficult to put real query, because of complexity.

It is something like

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.name, t2.name 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
left join table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
where t2.id = t1.ref_id
  and t1.ref_id IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', ...)
```

I found, that if I have inside IN clause only 4 or less values like this t1.ref_id IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4') it works very fast (16 ms). If I just add one id and make it 5 like this t1.ref_id IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5') execution time increases to 40 times and becomes 600 ms.

I got it on SQL Server 2014.

It looks like there is some parameter, which controls this behavior. I tried this query in another SQL server (SQL Server 2008) and I could not find any limit.

My question: Is there any parameter, which controls this kind of behavior? or how to increase this strange limit to 50 for example.

I just want to increase it up to 30-50 instead of 4. Of course I do not want to create IN clause with hundreds and thousands of values.

UPDATE1

Sorry, I forgot to put t3.name to select, otherwise it looks like t3 I do not need:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
from table1 t1, table2 t2
left join table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
where t2.id = t1.ref_id
  and t1.ref_id IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', ...)
```

UPDATE2

Looks like I found a reason. The issue was not about number of items inside IN. Later I reproduced this issue with less than 4 ids (even with 1). It happens, because some of ids was not presented in t1.ref_id. when there were the ids, which do not exist in t1.ref_id, when it was fast, when I added id, which does exist in t1.ref_id, when it becomes slow. In my previous example id1 - id4 was not presented in t1.ref_id and id5 was presented. This is why when I add id5 it becomes slow. It becomes slow even if I just put only 1 id (id5) inside IN clause. Finally index on t1.ref_id solved the problem. There was no magic around 4 or 5 ids. It is just a coincidence in my specific example.

Comment: Have you created an index on t1.ref_id?

Comment: You've done well to narrow down the difference. Now compare query plans between the slow and fast versions. What do you see. Press CTRL-L to see the query plans.

Comment: You should not mix implicit and explicit join syntax, you should rewrite to explicit syntax. It's ANSI standard since 1992! Is this query part of a stored procedure? Does it help if you add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, thanks. I am doing it right now.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks, but I cannot change it to implicit join. I use some product which generates SQL this is why I cannot change it. It is not a stored procedure. OPTION(RECOMPILE) I will try.

Comment: OPTION(RECOMPILE) does not make sense if I do not have stores procedure I think. and I do not have.

Comment: You should fix your first an biggest problem first, get rid of this product that produces queries in very very old syntax. No answer here can help you because with this product you cant implement it anyway

Comment: @GuidoG As I told you before, syntax here does not matter. It gives the same problem with both syntax. Your advice is like "change your old car, because it is old", but maybe I just need to refuel it.

Comment: I will try something simple and obvious :)
`EXEC sp_updatestats;`

Comment: @Zlelik The syntax does not matter now, but what if someone here posts an answer and you cannot use that answer because it requires altering your query in a way that this product does not supports ? That is the point I was trying to explain

Comment: Please add actual execution plan for both cases?

Comment: @GuidoG In my case it is nearly impossible to change the syntax. Type in google Documentum price, average Documentum project cost and you will see how much money company need to spend to switch from Documentum to something else. It is like you have wordpress for website,  you were using it for 5 years, you have 10000 articles, links between them, 500 customization in code and etc.

Comment: @GuidoG And now you find one place inside worpdress where they use join of the tables with comma. You created a bug with wordpress, but they answer you it is not critical, nobody cares, end users are not affected and they rejected your bug. Because of this you decided to switch to Joomla and move all your 10000 articles with all links and customization. How much time you will spend for this migration? Is it reasonable? What top management will tell to you, if you suggest this?

Comment: @GuidoG Most probably there is already existing software for Wordpress->Joomla migration, because it is very popular platforms, but let's assume that there is no this software or it cost 100000$ like it is in case with Documentum.

Comment: @Zlelik I get your point you can stop shooting at me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix the query.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.name, t2.name 
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.ref_id left join
     table3 t3 
     on t2.id = t3.id
where t1.ref_id in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', ...);
```

Based on the query, you have no need for `table3` -- unless you care about duplicate rows.  I would remove it.

Then, you need to consider indexes.  I would suggest `table1(ref_id, id, name)` and `table2(id, name)`.

Also, if `ref_id` is really a number, then don't put single quotes around the values in the list.  Mixing strings and numbers can confuse the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I cannot change syntax from comma separated tables to JOIN, because I use some product, where I am not allowed to change SQL directly.

Table3 I need, I forgot to select data from it. I changed my query in the UPDATE1.

ref_id is a string. id is kind of GUID which has numbers and letters like this 097777778018f16b.

Indexes I would understand if it is always would be slow. but why it is fast for 4 ids and slow for 5 ids? I also have another query which looks similar but takes data from different tables and it has the same issue. 4 values if fine, 5 is slow.

Comment: a product that produces queries with old join syntax ? dump it, now

Comment: @GuidoG It is called "DELL EMC Documentum" and they provide DQL language (Documentum Query Language) which is automatically converted to SQL by Documentum Content Server. I am writing this DQL query. There is LEFT join syntax, but there is no JOIN syntax. I tried to simulate JOIN with LEFT JOIN like this LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.ref_id ... where t2.id != '' and it works. but it still has the same problem with IN. Anyway, rewriting this Query with join will not help looks like. It is just fighting for beautiful syntax :)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Actually you are right.  It happens, because some of ids was not presented in t1.ref_id. when there were the ids, which do not exist in t1.ref_id, when it was fast, when I added id, which does exist in t1.ref_id, when it becomes slow. and your suggestion about indexes `table1(ref_id, id, name)` solved the problem.